# Where is Wirt's Cowbell (for Wirt's Case Scenario)?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

Where can I find Wirt's Cowbell for this achievement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wirt's Bell can be purchased from Squirt the Peddler in the Caldeum Bazaar (Act 2). It is under the miscellaneous tab.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Cowbell]

Well, it seems to be purchased from a vendor, though I don't recognize the location in the screenshot.

Comment: it's only me, or this look just like Dalaran with a NPC and a Druid ?

Comment: This is in Act 2, in the market below the Hidden Camp.

Comment: Note that from patch 1.0.4, this vendor is found next to the town way point

Answer (score 0):

It can be found in the hidden camp, southwest of stash, in Act 2.

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! This space is reserved for answers to the question.  If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.